# How to make xargs ping and head output as expected?

Tags: bash, shell-script, xargs, head

Given  an array of domains I would like to obtain their  IP addresses, in the following format:

```
98.139.183.24
98.137.236.24
```

This script

```
#!/bin/bash
domains=(yahoo.com yahoo.ca)
printf "%s\0" "${domains[@]}" | xargs -0 -t -n 1  ping -c 1 -w 3 | grep -E 'PING.*' | sed -r 's:^.*\((([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})\).*$:\1:'
```

gives the expected output. But initially I tried:
`printf "%s\0" "${domains[@]}" | xargs -0 -t -n 1  ping -c 1 -w 3 |  head -n 1 | sed -r 's:^.*\((([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})\).*$:\1:'` and the command exited with a signal 13 ( which,from what I  understand, means broken pipe ?!?). Obviously the issue is with `head` . Now I would like to explore why it does not work and if and eventually how I could make this long “wiener” work with `head`. I have not tried it yet but I am pretty sure it would work using a `for` construct and using `head` for each `ping`. Using `xargs` with the `-P` option also does not work. I guess the main issue would be that `head` is fed `xargs` output as one continous file ( did I say right or is it “input” ?).

EDIT1: My goal was to obtain the IP addresses of a set of website addresses and then check  to what organisations are those IPs registered too by using`whois` and piping its output to `sed` and then maybe do some grouping so I have only unique names, no repetitions. I agree that `dig` or `host` are much more thorough than `ping` but I am fairly certain the websites are small enough that only one IP address will be found for each domain. Nevertheless I think now I will go with `dig` ( or `host`; I have not decided yet) as others suggested.

To make it clear why I am interested in using `head` and not `grep` for what I need: I am just curious how it would be done(I am quite new to bash and linux in general) and I felt that it might clear up how piping works. That's all

Comment: I will be AFK for the next hour so don't expect a reply earlier folks

Comment: It's not clear why you want to use head, or what is your purpose. If you use head to only output one result it will kill the rest of results, obviously.

Comment: Moreover, if you only want to convert names to ip addresses using ping is one of the less efficient ways (rather use dig, host, nslookup).

Comment: As `host yahoo.com` (or reading about DNS) will show, a hostname can be bound to multiple IP addresses. [Why would you want only an arbitrary single IP address?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: @LatinSuD  see my edit.

Comment: @I0b0 I will be using host ( or dig). You can see i my edit why i initially  used ping instead

Answer (score 1):

`head -n 1` exits after the first line has been printed, and sends SIGPIPE to the writer (`xargs`) to say that there's no process left to read whatever it writes. In response `xargs` does what most processes do and kills its subprocesses (`ping`), prints a warning, probably sends SIGPIPE to its own parent, and then kills itself.

You'll notice, however, that since you haven't set `pipefail` in your script the exit code of the full script is zero - the exit code of the `sed` command.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3|xargs -n1 ping -w 1
```

or with grep, see  only non ping nodes

```
echo 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3|xargs -n1 ping -w 1|grep -b1 100
```